# The best way to use fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

### Problem Description

In my application I'm using tabs which contains Fragments, for that purpose I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` in which function `getItem(int position)` always creates a new instance of my Fragment and return it.

### Question

What is the best way to use Fragment Adapter Version 1 or Version 2?

### Source Code

#### FragmentFavorites.java

```
public class FragmentFavorites extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Gets Fragmnet view. */
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Logger.d("onCreateView(FragmentFavorites)");
        return rootView;
    }
};
```

#### FragmentCategories.java

```
public class FragmentCategories extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Gets Fragmnet view. */
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Logger.d("onCreateView(FragmentCategories)");
        return rootView;
    }
};
```

#### FragmentHome.java

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Gets Fragmnet view. */
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Logger.d("onCreateView(FragmentHome)");
        return rootView;
    }
};
```

#### FragmentFactory.java

```
public class FragmentFactory {
    
    private static final int F_FAVORITES_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int F_HOME_INDEX      = 1;
    private static final int F_CATEGORY_INDEX  = 2;
    
    /** Keeps the fragments which are put in the tabs of the main screen. */
    private static final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    static {
        fragmentsList.add(F_FAVORITES_INDEX, new FragmentFavorites());
        fragmentsList.add(F_HOME_INDEX, new FragmentHome());
        fragmentsList.add(F_CATEGORY_INDEX, new FragmentCategories());
    }
    
    public static int getCount() {
        return fragmentsList.size();
    }
    
    public static Fragment getFragment(int index) {
        return fragmentsList.get(index);
    }
};
```

#### SectionsPagerAdapter.java (Version 1)

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FragmentFactory.getFragment(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return FragmentFactory.getCount();
        }
}
```

#### SectionsPagerAdapter.java (Version 2)

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position) {
              case 0: return new FragmentFavorites();
              case 1: return new FragmentHome();
              case 2: return new FragmentCategories();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The adapter `getItem()` only gets called when the item needs to be created. If the fragment is already in memory, the previously created instance will be used.

By default, the view pager also has the next and previous fragments pre-instantiated as controlled by the offscreen page limit setting.

You should not store a large number of fragments for example in an array. That prevents them from being garbage collected and eats up resources such as memory. Also holding onto the fragment references does not prevent the fragment lifecycle methdos from being invoked.

If you want to increase the amount of fragments kept alive in memory, just use a larger offscreen page limit.

Comment: look like that in Version 1 `onCreateView` is not called for fragments and in Version it is called every time when I go from tab 0 to tab 2

Comment: Yes because there are more fragments than the off screen page limit wants to keep in memory.

Comment: okay I see, but in general which is the best way Version1 or Version2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FragmentPagerAdapter with ViewPager, so we have friendly swipe feature. Also the view pager automatically cache the fragments without needed to create a new instance everytime. We can set how much fragment we want to cache with `ViewPager.setOffScreenLimit()`